# unable to restore backup because not enough space

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

I tried restoring a backup I created from my iPhone (it had more than 20Gb free out of 64Gb) but when I wanted to restore this backup I found out the backup iTunes created was 61.5Gb, so whenever I try restoring it says not enough storage. Any way I could restore data still? I know I have 22Gb of photos, if it could help. 
I have tried to factory reset my phone so I can choose the "restore from itunes backup" option, and still I had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

That backup is awfully larger than it should be. I dont think you'll be able to restore it on that size, you'll need a 128GB model for the update to work since most OS sizes are between 8GB - 4GB of that base memory. Thats why you are having problems.

Comment: that's the problem that it's unexpectedly large, my factory restored iphone only has 55Gb of free storage. I'm asking if there is any way I could selectively restore data, or just remove the pictures from the itunes backup before attempting to restore.

Comment: @RedaDrissi you can't select them once you've backed up already

Comment: The iTunes backup is compressed and you can't select it. iCloud backups are much smaller.

Comment: so you mean there is no solution to recover the data in that backup?

Comment: Not other than restoring it on an iPhone or iPad with a larger size memory, which would be 128gb or 256gb

Comment: that'll be tough to find, a big storage iphone that's just laying around

Comment: Can you upgrade with your carrier? What model iPhone do you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81993/discussion-between-reda-drissi-and-melvin-jefferson).